# Не происходит авторизация на php (mvc)

Tags: php, mvc

Не происходит авторизация. Я думаю что неверно описан класс  Controller_Base.

```
<?php
// включим отображение всех ошибок
error_reporting (E_ALL);

'''// подключаем конфиг
include ('config.php');

// Соединяемся с БД
$dbObject = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$dbObject->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

// подключаем ядро сайта
include (SITE_PATH . DS . 'core' . DS . 'core.php');

// Загружаем router
$router = new Router();
// задаем путь до папки контроллеров.
$router->setPath (SITE_PATH . 'controllers');
// запускаем маршрутизатор
$router->start();
?>
```

Файл user.php

```
  }
        function login(){
            if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
                header("Location: /index.php");
                exit();
            }else{
            if(!isset($_REQUEST['username'])){
                $this->template->view('login');
            }else{
                $name = $_REQUEST['username'];
                $select = array(
                    'where' => "username = '".$name."'"
                );
                $model = new Model_Users($select);
                $model->fetchOne();
                $pass = $model->password;
                $rights = $model->rights;
                $id = $model->id;
                $pas = md5($_REQUEST['password']);
                if ($pass === $pas){
                    setcookie('username', $_REQUEST['username'], time()+60*60*24, '/');
                    setcookie('rights', $rights, time()+60*60*24, '/');
                    setcookie('id', $id, time()+60*60*24, '/');
                    echo "success";
                    return 'success';
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

Файл controller_base

```
<?php
// абстрактый класс контроллера
Abstract Class Controller_Base_Admin {

    protected $registry;
    protected $template;
    protected $layouts; // шаблон

    public $vars = array();

    // в конструкторе подключаем шаблоны
    function __construct() {
        // шаблоны
        $this->template = new Template($this->layouts, get_class($this));
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
            header("Location: /user/login/");
            exit();
        }
    }

    abstract function index();

}
```

Файл core.php

```
function __autoload($className) {
    print_r(get_declared_classes());
$filename = strtolower($className).'.php';
    // определяем класс и находим для него путь
    $expArr = explode('_', $className);
    if(empty($expArr[1]) OR $expArr[1] == 'Base'){
        $folder = 'classes';            
    }else{          
        switch(strtolower($expArr[0])){
            case 'controller':
                $folder = 'controllers';    
                break;
                 
            case 'model':                   
                $folder = 'models'; 
                break;
                 
            default:
                $folder = 'classes';
                break;
        }
    }
    // путь до класса
    $file = SITE_PATH . $folder . DS . $filename;
    // проверяем наличие файла
    if (file_exists($file) == false) {
        return false;
    }       
    // подключаем файл с классом
    include ($file);
}
```

Файл controller_base_admin

```
<?php
// абстрактый класс контроллера
Abstract Class Controller_Base_Admin {

    protected $registry;
    protected $template;
    protected $layouts; // шаблон

    public $vars = array();

    // в конструкторе подключаем шаблоны
    function __construct() {
        // шаблоны
        $this->template = new Template($this->layouts, get_class($this));
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
            header("Location: /user/login/");
            exit();
        }
    }

    abstract function index();

}
```

Comment: Для информации: чтобы исправить ошибку,  код не разглядывают, а *запускают*. Надо запускать свой код и выводить промежуточные результаты чтобы понять, в каком месте ошибка. Задавая вопрос следует избегать бессмысленных словосочетаний типа "не работает". Надо конкретно и подробно описывать свои действия, ожидаемый результат, и - самое главное - что в результате происходит.

Comment: Здравствуйте! При успешной авторизации должен произойти переход в личный кабинет пользователя.

Comment: очень хорошо. это ответ на один вопрос из пяти. что происходит *вместо этого?* Хотя конечно сейчас я вижу что действительно, *наверное* controller_base написан не совсем корректно. Например в нем нет вообще никакого упоминания ни логина, ни юзера

Comment: Я докинула еще один файл

Comment: А что здесь забыли метки HTML и CSS? Для привлечения излишнего внимания? Так эти методы тут только раздражают.

Comment: Это всё какой-то ужас. какие-то бессвязные телодвижения. Здесь не странно что не проходит авторизация. здесь странно что вообще хоть что-то работает. если работает

Comment: '''// - в PHP это не работает. дальше простыню не читал)))

Comment: Ну что мне еще необходимо скинуть, какой код, мне необходима помощь. Обратилась за помощью, а не затем чтоб мне указывали что раздражает. Я новичок. И у вас всех тоже были ошибки...прошу понимая и помощи!